# Parent placeholder rendered in Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

- Laravel Version: v8.41.0
- PHP Version: 8.0.5
- Sail Version: v1.5.1

#### Description:

I have an *a.blade.php* view that, in body, contains a *@yield* directive like this

`@yield('post_body_scripts')`

Then, the view is included in another one, *b.blade.php* that holds data for the *post_body_scripts* section

```
@extends('partials.layouts.app')
...
@include('c', ['foo' => 'bar'])
@section('post_body_scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/b.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

The included *c* view contains another part of the *post_body_scripts* section

```
@section('post_body_scripts')
@parent
<script src="https://cdn/ajsfile.js"></script>
@endsection
```

The **@parent** directive correctly works, but an hashtag starting placeholder is shown when the render of the view starts

```
<?php $__env->startSection('post_body_scripts'); ?>

##parent-placeholder-1a5ac98c3addb84257eb2d5b7ffee8f1cbf3b352##
<script src="https://cdn/ajsfile.js"></script>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?><?php /**PATH /var/www/html/resources/views/c.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Create a base view that contains a *@yield* directive;
2. Create a view that extends the previous one and uses a *@section* directive for the previous *yield*;
3. Include, in the view created at point 2, another sub view;
4. In the view included at point 3, use a *@section* directive that starts with *@parent* for the declared *yield*.

### Update

As notified to me in comments I tried using **@stack** directive but problem is still here.

a.blade.php

`@stack('post_body_scripts')`

b.blade.php

```
@push('post_body_scripts')
....
@endpush
```

c.blade.php

```
@push('post_body_scripts')
@parent
....
@endpush
```

Comment: Don't use `@section` for this kind of thing, use [`@stack`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks)

Comment: @Peppermintology thank you, I tried with it, but the "parent placeholder" error persists

Comment: No need to use `@parent` when using `@stack`. Push into the stack as much as you want, it'll get appended

Comment: @brombeer I confirm that mixing your comments and the one from Peppermintology it works correctly

Answer (score 1):

remove `@parent`

```
@parent not use with @stack or @push
```